# Robocopy what is the command to copy a dvd to my Hard Drive excluding a Folder?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, command-line, dvd, robocopy

I want to copy all the folders, subdirectories and files from a DVD to my hard drive excluding a Subdirectory, using `Robocopy`, what is the command for this task using this path?

Copy all from `D:\` excluding `D:\Programs\DVD IV\FileandDisk\Utilities\CCleaner`

I do not want to copy `CCleaner` and its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I do not want to copy CCleaner and its contents

> What is the command for this task?

Use the `/XD` (e**X**clude Directories matching given names/paths) option.

```
robocopy D:\ {dest} /MIR /XD "D:\Programs\DVD IV\FileandDisk\Utilities\CCleaner"
```

Notes:

- Replace `{dest}` with the (full or relative) path name of the folder you want to copy to.

  Example: `C:\Backup`.
- If `{dest}` contains `spaces` it **must** be quoted.

  Example: `"C:\My Backup"`.
- `/MIR` is **MIR**ror a directory tree - equivalent to `/PURGE` plus all subfolders `(/E)` (you probably want this option as well).
- `"D:\Programs\DVD IV\FileandDisk\Utilities\CCleaner"` **must** be quoted as it contains `spaces`.

---

**Destination options**

```
/A+:[RASHCNET] : Set file Attribute(s) on destination files + add.
/A-:[RASHCNET] : UnSet file Attribute(s) on destination files - remove.
          /FAT : Create destination files using 8.3 FAT file names only.

       /CREATE : CREATE directory tree structure + zero-length files only.
          /DST : Compensate for one-hour DST time differences.
        /PURGE : Delete dest files/folders that no longer exist in source.
          /MIR : MIRror a directory tree - equivalent to /PURGE plus all subfolders (/E)
```

> **Advanced options you'll probably never use**

```
           /EFSRAW : Copy any encrypted files using EFS RAW mode.
           /MT[:n] : Multithreaded copying, n = no. of threads to use (1-128)  #
                     default = 8 threads, not compatible with /IPG and /EFSRAW
                     The use of /LOG is recommended for better performance.

           /SECFIX : FIX file SECurity on all files, even skipped files.
           /TIMFIX : FIX file TIMes on all files, even skipped files.

               /XO : eXclude Older - if destination file exists and is the same date
                     or newer than the source - don’t bother to overwrite it.
               /XC : eXclude Changed files
               /XN : eXclude Newer files
               /XL : eXclude "Lonely" files and dirs (present in source but not destination)
                     This will prevent any new files being added to the destination.
               /XX : eXclude "eXtra" files and dirs (present in destination but not source)
                     This will prevent any deletions from the destination. (this is the default)

/XF file [file]... : eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards.
/XD dirs [dirs]... : eXclude Directories matching given names/paths.
                     XF and XD can be used in combination  e.g.
                     ROBOCOPY c:\source d:\dest /XF *.doc *.xls /XD c:\unwanted /S
```

Source [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) - Robust File and Folder Copy.

Comment: {dest} between quotes right? example "C:\Backup" ?

Comment: Yes. Answer fixed. I also added `/MIR` option as you probably want that as well.

Comment: @jedikeeper  Note: the `"`s are only required if the arguments contain `spaces`.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cc733145.aspx):

```
robocopy D:\ "c:\Target-Driectory" /MIR /XD "D:\Programs\DVD IV\FileandDisk\Utilities\CCleaner"
```

As you've not specified a destination I've gone with c:\Target-Driectory

/xd [ ...]
Excludes directories that match the specified names and paths.